# JSON API and django database

Tags: json, django, api

Hello I'm new to Django I'm trying to create my first application with Django using an API that return JSON.I want to know how to save this data to my database. this is the code I have so fat. forms.py:

```
from django import forms
import requests
from .models import Series
API_KEY = 'api_key'

class SeriesAPI(forms.Form):

    serie = forms.CharField(label='Search for Serie', max_length=100)

    def search(self):
        result = {}
        serie = self.cleaned_data['serie']
        endpoint = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key={api_key}&query={serie_name}'
        url = endpoint.format(
        api_key = API_KEY,
        serie_name = serie
        )
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            result = response.json()
            if result['total_results'] >= 1:
                id = result['results'][0]['id']
            else:
                return None

        return id

    def get_serie(self):
        result = {}
        endpoint = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/{id}?language=en-US&api_key={api_key}'
        url = endpoint.format(
            id = self.search(),
            api_key =  API_KEY 
        )
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            result = response.json()

        return result
```

Right now everything's good, I got the data and I can display it; I create a new form with only one input to store the data but I can't do it 
this is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    search_result = {}
    form = SeriesAPI(request.POST or None)
    if 'serie' in request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            search_result = form.get_serie()
        else:
            form = SeriesAPI()

    return render(request, 'series/serie.html', {'form': form, 'search_result': search_result})


class CreateSeries(generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('original_name', 'overview')
    model = models.Series

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super(CreateSeries, self).form_valid(form)
```

and this my template:

```
{% extends "series/base_series.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Series</h1>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

{% if search_result %}

<hr>

<h2>{{search_result.name}}</h2>
<img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{{ search_result.poster_path }}" alt="" style="width:250px;">

<form method="GET">
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

{% else %}

<p>Serie Not Found!</p>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Please help me

Comment: Your code is a bit unusual. I think most of what you have in the `SeriesAPI` form belongs in a library, and certainly not in a form. You also don't show the `urls.py`, so it's hard to say what's happening. Are you using both views? How? And do you get an error or just nothing in the DB?

Comment: Have you take a look at Django Rest Framework?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida which library you mean? I used this SeriesAPI only for call the api and I got the information and what I'm asking exactly that how I can save this data that I got with form on the database with another button I don't know how to do it "I'm a beginner"

Comment: @SaadHarakat I meant extracting that code to your own library, because it's doing things unrelated to "processing a form". But that's besides the point, it would be more useful of you showed your `urls.py`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida this is my urls.py : `app_name = 'serie'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^add/$', views.CreateSeries.as_view(), name='add')
]`

Comment: @SaadHarakat There's nothing connecting your views; in `index` you get the data through the API, but then you do nothing with it (you don't save it anywhere), and in `CreateSeries` you save the form, but you never get any API data (you're only saving the `serie` field). Where do you want to store the data you retrieve? Is there a model with appropriate fields for the response you get from the API?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I do have a model with some fields but I didn't connect it with the api yet, because I would get the data first and after that I have the choice to save it or not did you undesrtand what I mean? and I'm very sorry for your time

Comment: @SaadHarakat Ok, but then you have to think about how you are going to do it. Your `index` view retrieves the data from the API. Now you need to add logic to decide whether to save the data and then connect it to the model. That will just be a matter of creating (or retrieving) a instance of the model you already have, filling out the fields with data from the API and saving the instance.